# Вывод изображения из бд в Image

Tags: c#, wpf

На странице есть такой ListView, внутри которого содержится Image

```
<ListView x:Name="BuildingObjectsListView"
              Grid.Row="2"
              BorderThickness="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="332" Background="#4CFFFFFF">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="132*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,0,12,0" Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image  Source="{Binding Path=HouseProject, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding CadastralNumber}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

На странице c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace KraftHouse.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для BuildingObjectsPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BuildingObjectsPage : Page
    {
        public static BuildingCompanyEntities db { get; set; }
        public string clients;

        public BuildingObjectsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            BuildingObjectsListView.ItemsSource = GetClients().ToList();
         }

        public static IEnumerable<BuildingObjects> GetClients()
        {
            using (var db = new BuildingCompanyEntities())
            {
                return db.BuildingObjects.ToList();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Для изображения такой конвертер

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace KraftHouse
{
    class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string bytes = (string)value;

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(bytes, UriKind.Relative);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

В базе данных sql server в таблице BuildingObjects путь к изображению хранится в varchar
Все это сделал, но изображение не появляется

Comment: Плохо, очень плохо использовать контролы, как источник данных, научитесь делать привязки! По поводу вопроса, что вам отдает `GetClients().ToList();`? Там есть публичное, `string` СВОЙСТВО `HouseProject` (`public string HouseProject {get;set;}`), которое содержит в себе изображение?

Comment: Вы используете WPF как Winforms. И из конвертера вам надо возвращать не `BitmapImage`, а строку, путь к картинке. Другими словами, вам не нужен конвертер, просто уберите его. С чего вы вообще взяли, что он нужен? :) Если же у вас там картинка в свойстве лежит, а не путь к ней, то при чем тут вообще тогда `string`?